# DevDemon Subscriptions Not Renewing Automatically - All are "Skipped"

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

When my first group of subscribers came up for renewal, all of them slipped into Past Due status.

- Nothing was in the Subscription event log to indicate anything had happened.
- Stripe had no record of attempted payments.

On the advice of DevDemon I manually backdated the "next retry" date on one of the subscriptions (in the database), then manually visited the Subscriptions CRON url in my browser.

The process ran, and behold, the renewal process worked. So I repeated this process for all the other past_due subscriptions.

But the next day, more of them had failed to renew. So I started the process over again. And once again, when I triggered the update via the web, it worked fine.

Why would CRON based updates fail, but when I trigger it via the web, everything works?

Answer (score 0):

FIX: I had both: 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.* IPs in the "Test IPs" field. (I think this was the default setting).

When the update process was run (triggered by a CRON job), Automat:ee would call the Subscriptions action URL, but the IP was obviously the local machine IP, 127.0.0.1 and the entire update process would be treated as a test.

That explains why manually triggering it in the browser worked. I removed those IPs from the list and it worked after that.